# Get multiple category names from permalink

Tags: categories, permalinks

I am trying to get category names for the ones that are available in permalink. e.g. I have the following permalink structure.

```
abc.com/product-category/category-1/category-2/
```

Where as **category-1** and **category-2** both are categories. When I try `$wp_query->get_queried_object()`, it just returns info related to **category-2**. How can I get details of *category-1* using any existing WordPress functions?

Answer (score 0):

The function [`get_category_parents`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_category_parents/) will get you a string of the parent categories given the ID of a child category. So, like this:

```
$cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$catid = $cat->cat_ID;
$parentcats = get_category_parents ($catid, false, '|', false);
```

This will give you something like `category1|category2|category3`. Follow the link above to see what other options you have. If you want to do more complicated stuff, you could split the string using [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).